# Office RibbonUI ApplicationMenu Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm having weird issues with the LargeImageSource for the Application menu (using Office2007Blue theme)

My image is 48x48 but it appears to be scaling down to 10x10.  It's not using SmallImageSource at all.

```
<r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command>
                    <r:RibbonCommand
                        SmallImageSource="images/icon.png"
                        LargeImageSource="images/icon.png"
                        ToolTipTitle="Application Menu"
                        ToolTipDescription="Click here to open files or close the application." />
                </r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                    <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem.Command>
                        <r:RibbonCommand 
                            LabelTitle="_Close" 
                            LabelDescription="Close the Application"
                            />
                    </r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem.Command>
                </r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
            </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the image's printed dimensions fixed it.  The button doesn't look at the pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Ribbon is full of bugs. This one in particular is because the SmallImageSource Image is hardcoded to 16x16 in the RibbonApplicationMenu's control template. LargeImageSource isn't even used anywhere in the default theme.